# Sharing from macOS with Linux guest

Tags: mojave, unix, sharing

I need to share a directory from macOS and access it from Linux.

What is my best option, SMB or AFP (I am not mentioning NFS because I [read](https://photographylife.com/afp-vs-nfs-vs-smb-performance) of its poor performance)? I need support for extended attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The current way is SMB

If you go to System Preferences->Sharing and tick the File Sharing button the dialog shows

> Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes, at smb://192.168.0.xx

The last address could be another local address depending on your network setup

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to system preferences
2. go to Sharing
3. Check file sharing, add folders etc that you want to share.
4. Click on options
5. Check share files and folders using SMB
6. Click the checkmark next to the user account you plan on using. For my network without doing this setup I was unable to access on Ubuntu, Fedora or Raspian.
7. click done.
8. Go back to system preferences main page and go to Netowrk
9. Click the network adapter in use and click on advanced.
10. Go to WINS tab.
11. Note down the Workgroup name.
12. Now in ubuntu use the file manager and go to network and you should be able to see your computer and use your account credentials to login, make sure you used the correct workgroup.

I hope that works for you.